# Merging dataframes and creating NaN values without reordering

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge two dataframes on 'word'. They look like this:

df1

```
   word    other_data
0  hello      1
1  how        2
2  are        3
3  you        4
```

df2

```
   word    
0  hello      
1  ,
2  how        
3  are        
4  you        
5  ?
```

The result I want is this:

```
   word    other_data
0  hello      1
1  ,          NaN
2  how        2
3  are        3
4  you        4
5  ?          NaN
```

The closest I've been able to get to the desired result is with this, but it yields a df not in the original order.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='right')
```

Comment: `df2['other_data']=df2['word'].map(df1.set_index('word')['other_data'])`

Comment: I'd go with the `map` here if `word` in df1 is a unique key. Otherwise, the row ordering is fixed using a left merge: `pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left')`

Comment: This seems to be an issue, where `right` is not preserving the key ordering: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27453

Answer (score 0):

What you need is join, this is done on pandas buy setting the index of the other data frame to the desired key and specifying the key for the join operation, this is as simple as :

```
df2.join(df1.set_index('word'), on='word')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try this.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='word')
```

outer means it will create a series of keys as a union of keys from df1 and df2, while right will only use keys from df2.

on specifies specifically which column to join on.

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is `reindex`

```
df=df1.set_index('word').reindex(df2.word).reset_index()
Out[20]: 
    word  other_data
0  hello         1.0
1      ,         NaN
2    how         2.0
3    are         3.0
4    you         4.0
5      ?         NaN
```

Comment: thank you but when I try this I get the following error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis